# Is there a way to render the vector pass of the fire and smoke?

Tags: rendering, vector

I want to use Blender to render the optical flow (vector pass) of something like fire or smoke for further research. I realize that I cannot directly render the vector pass of such volumes like solid objects. Luckily, I found that it has the option to display vectors and display them in the 3D view.
[image]
My question is how to get the raw data of these vectors and how to convert it to the camera viewpoint to replace direct rendering.

Comment: You want the raw data as values or do you want to render something that looks like what you see in the _3D Viewport_? For the latter, go to _View_ > _Viewport Render Animation_.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thanks for your comment. I prefer the former because the latter has been mapped to another meaning. The picture here is only used to indicate that the Blender can obtain the vectors of the volume.